# How can i read the log when App from not running to active?

Tags: ios, swift

My App's 3D-touch doesn't work when app was force closed (it runs well when app form suspend to active). So, I want to catch the log of launchOptions.

But, when I force close app, the console stop catching log anymore.

Please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do force close the app your Xcode stops the execution of it what you could do after that is attache the app running again.
Once you close it, open the app again (once was closed by force) and go to *Debug > Attach to Process* and your apps name should be there, select it and it will wait to the app for start, this works with a device, not sure with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

info.plist

```
<key>UIApplicationShortcutItems</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle</key>
        <string>Add New User</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemType</key>
        <string>com.vss.Qiuck-Action-Sample.Add</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle</key>
        <string>Add</string>
        <key>UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType</key>
        <string>UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeAdd</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if let shortcutitem = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        if shortcutitem.type == "com.vss.Qiuck-Action-Sample.Add" {
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        }
    }

    return true
}
}
```